# Record does not exist when using record transform

Tags: netsuite, restlet, suitescript2.0

Via Celigo I am calling a RESTlet script.
This is my script:

```
define(['N/log', 'N/file', 'N/query', 'N/record', 'N/runtime'],
    function (log, file, query, record, runtime) {


        function customerToVendor(request) {

            log.error('recordDetails', JSON.stringify(request));

            try {
                var objRecord = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                    fromId: request.customerId,
                    toType: record.Type.VENDOR,
                    isDynamic: true,
                });
                var objRecordId = objRecord.save();

                var response = {};
                response['info'] = objRecordId;

                return response;

            } catch (e) {
                log.error('ERROR', String(e));
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Very straight forward. I want to transform a Customer also into a Vendor. However I am getting a response that the record does not exist:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "RCRD_DSNT_EXIST",
    "message": "{\"type\":\"error.SuiteScriptError\",\"name\":\"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST\",\"message\":\"That record does not exist.\",\"stack\":[\"Error\n    at RecordInvoker.save (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/serverRecordService.js:371:13)\n    at NetSuiteObject.thenableFunction() .....
,\"notifyOff\":false},\"id\":\"4286\",\"notifyOff\":false,\"userFacing\":true}"

  }
}
```

The customer record with id 4286 is existing:
[image]

So what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It could be role permission or restriction problem.

Does the integration role have permission to see customers? or is there any restriction related to subsidiaries or employees?

Something you can do is assign the role to yourself and check that you're able to see the customer.

Comment: user has administrator role as well and can see customer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).